# WebSocket URL variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I have this JS code, that're trying connecting to a WebSocket, but I have a problem with the URL variable.

```js
var tipoChat = 1;
var escolherWebSocket = 1;
var unidade = prompt('Qual o IP do Provador?');
var loja = prompt('Qual o codigo da Loja?');
var url;
ws = new WebSocket(url);
        

// tipoChat 1 Produto
// tipoChat 2 Vendedor
// tipoChat 3 Atendente


function chatProduto() {
    tipoChat = 1;

    $("#btnProduto").addClass("btn-menuStyle-active");
    $("#btnAtendente").removeClass("btn-menuStyle-active");
    $("#btnVendedor").removeClass("btn-menuStyle-active");

     $("#provador-produto").removeClass("show-chat1");
     $("#provador-produto").removeClass("show-chat2");
     

}

function chatVendedor() {
    tipoChat = 2;

    $("#btnProduto").removeClass("btn-menuStyle-active");
    $("#btnAtendente").removeClass("btn-menuStyle-active");
    $("#btnVendedor").addClass("btn-menuStyle-active");

     $("#provador-produto").addClass("show-chat2");
     $("#provador-produto").removeClass("show-chat1");
   


}

function chatAtendente() {
    tipoChat = 3;

    $("#btnProduto").removeClass("btn-menuStyle-active");
    $("#btnAtendente").addClass("btn-menuStyle-active");
    $("#btnVendedor").removeClass("btn-menuStyle-active");

     $("#provador-produto").addClass("show-chat1");
     $("#provador-produto").removeClass("show-chat2");
     



}


function conectar() {
    $('#btnConectar').hide();
    $('#btnDesconectar').show();
    
                ws.onopen = function () {

                    $('#messages').prepend('Connected <br/>');
                    $('#cmdSend').click(function () {

                        ws.send($('#txtMessage').val());

                        $('#txtMessage').val('');

                    });
                    
   
}
}

switch (tipoChat) {

    case "1": // Chat Produto

        switch (escolherWebSocket) {

            case "1": //CBYK
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            case "2": //Centauro
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            default:
                alert("Código de Socket Inválido");
        }

    case "2": // Chat Vendedor

        switch (escolherWebSocket) {
            case "1":
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            case "2":
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            default:
                alert("Código de Socket Inválido");
        }

    case "3": //Chat atendente
        switch (escolherWebSocket) {
            case "1":
                var url = 'ws://example0';

                break;

            case "2":
                var url = 'ws://example1';
                break;

            default:
                alert("Código de Socket Inválido");      
}}
```

And This is my error on console:

**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'undefined' is invalid.**

Someone can say say why the Switch is not setting the Url variable? 
It works only when I assign a value on console.

**EDIT**:
For some reason, when I call URL variable on console, the result is undefined, even I initializing WebSocket after switch. I really don't know why URL variable is not being defined

```js
var typeChat = 1;
var escolherWebSocket = 1;
var url;

switch (typeChat) {

    case "1": // Chat Produto

        switch (escolherWebSocket) {

            case "1": //CBYK
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            case "2": //Centauro
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            default:
                alert("Código de Socket Inválido");
        }

    case "2": // Chat Vendedor

        switch (escolherWebSocket) {
            case "1":
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            case "2":
                var url = 'ws://example0';
                break;

            default:
                alert("Código de Socket Inválido");
        }

    case "3": //Chat atendente
        switch (escolherWebSocket) {
            case "1":
                var url = 'ws://example0';

                break;

            case "2":
                var url = 'ws://example1';
                break;

            default:
                alert("Código de Socket Inválido");      
}}

ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

Comment: From one portuguese speaking guy to another... Please write the variables in english, it's so much easier to read for everyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize `WebSocket` with an undefined URL, like you are here:

```
var url;
ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

You should do your `switch` statement before initializing `new WebSocket(url)`.

```
var url;
switch (tipoChat) {
    case 1:
        url = 'foo';
}
ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

Comment: For some reason, when I call URL variable on console, the result is undefined, even I initializing WebSocket after switch. I really don't know why URL variable is not being defined

Comment: i've updated the question with the code that arent working

Comment: Right, I see what it is. You're defining new `url` variables in each `case`. Set the existing `url` variable.

Instead of `var url = 'ws://example0';` do `url = 'ws://example0';`

Comment: Great! In this case, have a Switch inside another Switch does not affect js to assign variables?

Comment: As far as variable assignments go, you should be fine. Nested switch statements isn't the most readable or best practice JavaScript, but it should work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the 'url' variable in the top. Because you are creating a websocket with the 'url' variable without initializing it first. So 'url' variable is undefined at the moment.

Or you create socket where you are assigning to 'url' variable i.e. inside the switch block cases.